# "Впервые минуты" как пишется - слитно, раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, предлоги

> впервые минуты

Как пишется - слитно, раздельно или через дефис?

Comment: @farid, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: в первые минуты. Это сочетание порядкового числительного с предлогом, пишется раздельно.
[Впервы́е](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5&all=x) — ***наречие***, пишется слитно.  Напр.: Впервые в жизни у неё была отдельная комната.

Comment: Серж, я позволила себе подправить Ваш ответ (поставила ударение и внесла ссылку). Надеюсь, Вы не против.

Comment: Римма Михайлова, спасибо!